Server side component in client side component
I have a client-side component that fetches data, but I want the data to be visible to the browser, I know it's possible.
I can get it done when using simple strings and passing that string as a child to the server side component
When I view source and the string is visible, but as soon as I add an array...nothing is visible
At the moment I'm loading a server component as a prop and a children ReactNode:
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { StateLoading } from "@/shared/enums/loading";
import { useSelectorEffect } from "@/hooks/useSelector";
import { useAppSelector } from "@/hooks/store.hooks";

import styles from "@/styles/core/_category.module.scss";

import CategoryItem from "./CategoryItem";
import { Preview } from "../interfaces/preview";

interface DisplayProps<T> {
  statusSelector: (state: any) => string;
  fetchAction: any;
  slot: any;
  title: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Category = <T extends Preview>({
  statusSelector,
  fetchAction,
  slot,
  children,
}: DisplayProps<T>) => {
  const isClientLoaded = true;
  const isLoading = useAppSelector(statusSelector) === StateLoading.LOADING;
  return (
    <>
      {slot}
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default Category;

And where I'm using the above in here:
"use client";

import { useAppSelector } from "@/hooks/store.hooks";
import Category from "@/shared/components/Category";
import CategoryItem from "@/shared/components/CategoryItem";
import { Preview } from "@/shared/interfaces/preview";
import {
  selectStatus,
  getComics,
  selectComicsPreview,
} from "@/store/comics/comicsSlice";
import Link from "next/link";

const ComicsDisplay = () => {
  const items = useAppSelector(selectComicsPreview);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link href={"/"}>Back to main Page</Link>
      </div>
      <Category<any>
        slot={<CategoryItem>what</CategoryItem>} // This I can see on the page and when I view source
        statusSelector={selectStatus}
        fetchAction={getComics}
        title="Comics Category"
      >
        <CategoryItem>
          {items?.map((item: any) => `${item.title}`)} //This I can only see on the page
        </CategoryItem>
        {/* */}
      </Category>
    </>
  );
};

export default ComicsDisplay;

And the server component is quite simple:
import React from "react";

const CategoryItem = ({
  children,
}: {

  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  return (
    <>

      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default CategoryItem;


The reason you can see the string in your example is because the children of that component are already available when provided by the server. The content that you're trying to render from the items array is not visible in the page's source because the content is fetched from the browser.
When looking at the page's source, you're only reading the html returned by the server (no JS gets executed), meaning that, in that case, the fetch never runs and thus nothing gets rendered.
If you need this data to be available in the page's source (when no JS is available) then you must fetch this from a server and pass it to this component through props.

I did an experiment with just fetching the data and passing it to the  component and it worked fine, I could see the markup when I viewed source, but this makes the redux store redundant, I've seen  a few tutorials for for redux and next ssr but they're with the page router and getServerSideProps do you know of any information to use redux serverside with app router?

Personally I haven't used Redux in a really long time, and I've never used it for Next.js. In my cases, I've haven't had the need to store fetched data globally and I very much prefer to do some "prop drilling", though if your components are actually modular, it doesn't feel very much like "drilling". Simple reason being, you get to keep most of your components server side by avoiding the need of hooks. There is however an example made by the Next.js team themselves, might be worth checking it out.

Yes, that's what I used to set up this project and there's no SSR, I probably don't need to use redux for what I'm doing, but I would like to gain some experience, now I either, implement an older way of next/redux ssr using getServerSide props, or a  node/express server which I've seen, carry on and forget the SSR, or abandon redux for this project, back to the drawing board
